# store data temporarily before mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql

I think there is a limit to the amount of mysql connections you can have open. Would there be a way to store data from users temporarily and then insert it in one go to the database? Or how else would you manage say 200 000 people making facebook status updates? (because I dont you could simply open 200k connections and put the info in.)

thanks.

Comment: You *could* open 200000 simultaneous connections and do 200000 simultaneous commits just fine. It may be a bit slow, but it works.

Comment: If you have 200k users you must be actively using caching. So you can keep data in cache before writing into database. This will be helpful for performance too. Otherwise you can simply open that many connections.

Comment: check this for more info - https://www.google.com/search?q=+site%3Ahighscalability.com+architecture&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: In your example, you'd be caching 200,000 updates so you'll maybe run out of RAM instead of running out of connections. Running a site that would have 200k *simultaneous* updates isn't just a matter of taking a site doing 1 update and running it with 200k users. Don't plan too far ahead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might for example use a queue, whereby a single process gets the INSERTs (through interprocess communication, or via socket, even if - in that case - you'd have 200.000 connections to the queue server, or by storing files into a "spool" directory).

Then the process "reaps" the queue, possibly coalescing the INSERTS using extended syntax in case of MySQL, and sends them to the DB.

This is only useful if the whole job of outsourcing the INSERT to the process is much faster than sending it to the DB, otherwise the cost and the problems (e.g., after the outsourcing, the Web server thinks the DB is updated, but it actually is not, and won't be for a (little?) time until the reaper gets to it) outweigh the benefits.

You could make the whole process more resilient if the reaper process were capable of throttling or halting the Web server in case of overload: i.e., say that MySQL can only process X inserts per minute of sustained, even with INSERT DELAYED and such, and the inbound rate is more than that. Then at each iteration the reaper process will note that the queue is growing longer. Over a given limit, the process might set a flag so that new users receive an error message and are prevented from generating further inserts.

In the inbound > outbound situation, something's gonna give *anyway*, so at least this way you protect existing connections and provide a "soft fail" mode.

You might also implement a local cache using shared memory: each PHP process places the INSERTS in shared memory (with locking!). If there are more than X tuples waiting, or if the older tuple is older than Y seconds, all tuples are coalesced in a single INSERT that gets sent to MySQL, and the cache is emptied. This way the whole process is pretty lightweight, uses no network (but a bit of memory), and the load on MySQL decreases appreciably - coalesced INSERTs can be 100x faster than separate INSERTs, and index disable/enable tricks may be employed also.